# How to know total Technical and Unknow Bounce from Journey Builder E-mail's

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql

I noticed that the report from Analytics Builder does not have this field. Is there a way to know this with SQL? Only the report "Journey Builder Email Send Summary" shows me is the Soft, Hard and Block. I know that the Technical is a type of Soft Bounce, but i would like to know the separates records.

Other the field that i miss is the Total Open and Click rates (only has the unique rates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s an example of a very generic query, that will pull all the tracking data from Data Views into one table. All you need to do is create a Data Extension with the following fields:

```
SubscriberKey
EmailName
SentDate
OpenDate
OpenIsUnique
ClickDate
ClickIsUnique
BounceDate
BounceCategory
BounceSubcategory
BounceType
UnsubscribeDate
JourneyActivityObjectID
```

and run the following query, either in [Query Studio](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/05/query-studio-for-marketing-cloud/) or in Automation Studio:

```
SELECT 
s.SubscriberKey, 
j.EmailName, 
s.EventDate as SentDate, 
o.EventDate as OpenDate, 
o.IsUnique as OpenIsUnique,
c.EventDate as ClickDate, 
c.IsUnique as ClickIsUnique,
b.EventDate as BounceDate, 
b.BounceCategory, 
b.BounceSubcategory,
b.BounceType,
u.EventDate as UnsubscribeDate,
ja.JourneyActivityObjectID

FROM _Sent s LEFT JOIN _Job as j ON s.JobID = j.JobID 
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Click c ON s.JobID = c.JobID  and s.ListID = c.ListID and s.BatchID = c.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID and c.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Bounce b ON s.JobID = b.JobID and s.ListID = b.ListID and s.BatchID = b.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID and b.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Unsubscribe u ON s.JobID = u.JobID and s.ListID = u.ListID and s.BatchID = u.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = u.SubscriberID and u.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _JourneyActivity ja ON s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
```

You can filter further down using the JourneyActivityObjectID column - if it's not empty, this determines that the Send was a Journey Builder send.

You can read more about Data Views [here](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless how the email was sent all bounces are logged in the _bounce dataview. You can join this to the _journeyactivity dataview to narrow it down to an journey\activity